# Closing an unfilled array with user input in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working with arrays in java. I have written a code where the user inputs a string with numbers and characters, and then the program prints out the integers. The array has an index of 10 integers, and if the user does not input enough integers to fill the array then they are filled with the constant Integer.MIN_Value. I want to be able to close the array, so if the array is not filled with 10 integers it will close on the last integer entered by the user instead of filling the elements with the minimum value.

...

```
private int[] intArray = new int[10]; 

public StringToIntArray() {
    for(int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {  
    Arrays.fill(intArray, Integer.MIN_VALUE);  
        if (intArray[i] == Integer.MIN_VALUE){  //index equals min_value then the index is 'empty'.
        intArray[i] = 0;        
        }
    } 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Boolean skipErrors = true;
    String str = new String();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringToIntArray array = new StringToIntArray(); 
    
    
    System.out.println("Enter a string");   
    str = input.nextLine();                         
    array.scanStringToIntArray(str, skipErrors);  
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array.intArray));  
        
}


public boolean scanStringToIntArray(String str, boolean skipErrors) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(str);
    int i = 0;

    while(input.hasNext() == true) { 
        
        if(!input.hasNextInt()) { 
            input.next();
        
        } 
        else{
            intArray[i] = input.nextInt();
            i++;
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

...

I've been really struggling with arrays, so I'm not sure how I can close this. I want to say that I should have a conditional statement where the loop ends when it detects the MIN_VALUE, but I don't know if that's correct.

Comment: Create a new array with the desired size and copy the elements from the original array to the new array. Note however that you could use an ArrayList<Integer> instead. The later will grow or shrink as needed.

Comment: Seems you need to use a `List<Integer>` instead of an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that 10 is an upper limit for the number of values, You could do it like this parse and store the values in a temporary array and when finished create an array of the right size and copy thevalues.

```
public class StringToIntArray {

   
    private final int[] intArray; // we set this when we know the final size in the constructor

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
       final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        final String str = input.nextLine();
        final StringToIntArray array = new StringToIntArray(str);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array.intArray));

    }

    // Constructor gets the line to parse the values from
    public StringToIntArray(final String str) {
        intArray = scanStringToIntArray(str);
    }

    // parses the values and returns an array of the right size
    public int[] scanStringToIntArray(final String str) {
        final Scanner input = new Scanner(str);
        final int[] temp = new int[10];
        int i = 0;
        while (input.hasNext() == true) {
            if (!input.hasNextInt()) {
                input.next();
            }
            else {
                temp[i] = input.nextInt();
                i++;
            }
        }
        input.close(); // REMARK: even better use try with resources
        final int[] result = new int[i];
        System.arraycopy(temp, 0, result, 0, i); // fastest way to copy between arrays
        return result;
    }

}
```